# Using AND and OR for different based parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the below query.

The issue I have is with the following line of the query:

```
  AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DateOfBirth)
```

This is how the parameters are set as an example:

```
    --works correctly with an OR for DateOfBirth
    --DECLARE @SearchWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1995'
    --DECLARE @LowerDate DATE = '01 Jan 1995'
    --DECLARE @UpperDate DATE = '31 Dec 1995'
```

This displays the Clients with "1995" in one of the text fields, and all clients born between those dates.

```
    --works correctly with an AND for DateOfBirth
    --DECLARE @SearchWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'mich'
    --DECLARE @LowerDate DATE = NULL
    --DECLARE @UpperDate DATE = NULL
```

This displays all Clients who have mich somewhere in one of the text fields.

The first set of parameters get the correct result by using **OR** DateOfBirth BETWEEN where the second set of parameters get the correct result by using **AND** DateOfBIrth BETWEEN

How could the query be changed for it to work for both types of parameters being passed?

```
    CREATE TABLE #SearchWords
    (
        ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
        Word NVARCHAR(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO #SearchWords
    (
        Word
    )
    SELECT 
        value 
    FROM 
        STRING_SPLIT(@SearchWords, ' ')  
    WHERE 
        TRIM(value) <> ''

SELECT
    ClientID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    VerificationCode,
    DateOfBirth
FROM Client c
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM #SearchWords s
          WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
        )
  AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DateOfBirth)

  drop table #SearchWords
```

Sample Data with Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68162/15 (Query 3 is broken, shouldn't show Richard 1995 and others that don't meet the criteria)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients](
    [ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FIrstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [VerificationCode] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
)

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (206, N'Richard 1995', N'Douglas', CAST(N'1948-01-03' AS Date), N'bee')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (404, N'thank', N'yourselves', CAST(N'1995-12-03' AS Date), N'whattt')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (670, N'Ida 1995', N'Delgado', CAST(N'1995-02-03' AS Date), N'mild')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (1506, N'George', N'Coleman', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'brilliance')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (2384, N'Lewis', N'Rice', CAST(N'1995-04-03' AS Date), N'instrument')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (2600, N'Lisa', N'Stanley', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'rice')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (2974, N'Hammett', N'Hopkins', CAST(N'1995-05-03' AS Date), N'snuggle')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (2984, N'Lionel', N'Knox', CAST(N'1995-05-03' AS Date), N'disappoint')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3105, N'Ciaran', N'Delgado', CAST(N'1995-11-03' AS Date), N'strip')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3206, N'Lionel', N'Stanley', CAST(N'1995-02-03' AS Date), N'reflect')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3317, N'Ethan', N'Rice', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'bay')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3534, N'Jack', N'Vance', CAST(N'1995-04-03' AS Date), N'security')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3654, N'Elmo', N'Smith', CAST(N'1995-01-03' AS Date), N'sum')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3881, N'Michelle', N'Watts', CAST(N'1995-11-03' AS Date), N'night')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (4533, N'Otto', N'Hopkins', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'appeal')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (4929, N'Carlos', N'Harrison', CAST(N'1995-02-03' AS Date), N'gree')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (5052, N'Hiram', N'Nunez', CAST(N'1995-08-03' AS Date), N'rumor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (5148, N'Stephanie', N'Russell', CAST(N'1995-05-03' AS Date), N'expect')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (5240, N'Kato', N'Gibbs', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'appearance')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (5261, N'Josiah', N'St. Onge', CAST(N'1995-11-03' AS Date), N'motivatio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (5910, N'Dolan', N'Jensen', CAST(N'1995-09-03' AS Date), N'clash')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (6112, N'Kassie', N'Wolf', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'marriage')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (6487, N'Hiram', N'Gibbs', CAST(N'1995-08-03' AS Date), N'precisio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (6991, N'Arsenio', N'Merrill', CAST(N'1995-08-03' AS Date), N'perform')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (7136, N'Nancy', N'Warner', CAST(N'1995-11-03' AS Date), N'note')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (7452, N'Gil', N'Summerfield', CAST(N'1995-07-03' AS Date), N'emergency')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (7546, N'Kyle', N'Rice', CAST(N'1995-04-03' AS Date), N'eliminate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (7926, N'Ida', N'Gibbs', CAST(N'1995-10-03' AS Date), N'unity')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (8358, N'Honorato', N'Russell', CAST(N'1995-02-03' AS Date), N'course')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (8603, N'Jodi', N'Watts', CAST(N'1995-01-03' AS Date), N'bottle')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (9610, N'Todd', N'Rose', CAST(N'1995-03-03' AS Date), N'great')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (9823, N'Bill', N'Clarke', CAST(N'1995-10-03' AS Date), N'standard')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (9973, N'Janet', N'Mccoy', CAST(N'1995-05-03' AS Date), N'leftovers')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (10941, N'Hiram', N'Hopkins', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'visible')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (11010, N'Lionel', N'Rice', CAST(N'1995-07-04' AS Date), N'ghostwriter')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (11602, N'Gennifer', N'Russell', CAST(N'1995-01-04' AS Date), N'vessel')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (11803, N'Otto', N'Mcclain', CAST(N'1995-01-04' AS Date), N'skilled')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (11881, N'Yolanda', N'Summerfield', CAST(N'1995-04-04' AS Date), N'feel')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (12080, N'Sherri', N'Chaney', CAST(N'1995-09-04' AS Date), N'court')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (12378, N'Hiram', N'Chaney', CAST(N'1995-11-04' AS Date), N'routine')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (12828, N'Carlos', N'Rose', CAST(N'1995-03-04' AS Date), N'treasurer')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (13065, N'Lionel', N'Gibbs', CAST(N'1995-02-04' AS Date), N'stride')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (13178, N'Josiah', N'Montgomery', CAST(N'1995-01-04' AS Date), N'reductio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (13933, N'Hiram', N'Rowland', CAST(N'1995-03-04' AS Date), N'ballot')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (14239, N'Samuel', N'Russell', CAST(N'1995-04-04' AS Date), N'workshop')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (14253, N'Donovan', N'Gibbs', CAST(N'1995-08-04' AS Date), N'economist')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (14309, N'Carlos', N'LaPine', CAST(N'1995-04-04' AS Date), N'virgi')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (14332, N'Ida', N'Vega', CAST(N'1995-03-04' AS Date), N'brother')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (14337, N'Donovan', N'Randolph', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'art')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (14592, N'Josiah', N'Sanchez', CAST(N'1995-05-04' AS Date), N'launch')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (14920, N'Brandon', N'Mercado', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'exploit')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (15081, N'Richard', N'Coffey', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'stereotype')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (15347, N'Jarrod', N'Wolf', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'east')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (15607, N'Robert', N'Jensen', CAST(N'1995-02-04' AS Date), N'thoughtful')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (16662, N'Samuel', N'Vega', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'seize')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (17284, N'Francine', N'Bazinaw', CAST(N'1995-01-04' AS Date), N'native')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (17301, N'Kato', N'Harrison', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'jest')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (17576, N'Troy', N'Mcclain', CAST(N'1995-03-04' AS Date), N'discipline')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (17645, N'Jodi', N'Randolph', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'relaxatio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (18190, N'Hasad', N'Duncan', CAST(N'1995-03-04' AS Date), N'secretary')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (18362, N'Darren', N'Warner', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'charge')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (18771, N'Lionel', N'Gibbs', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'bank')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (18818, N'Erica', N'Mathis', CAST(N'1995-02-04' AS Date), N'surround')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (18830, N'Carlos', N'Rogers', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'reaso')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (19332, N'Kyle', N'Sanchez', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'flu')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (20053, N'Susie', N'Newton', CAST(N'1995-09-04' AS Date), N'concept')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (20070, N'Jennifer', N'Nielsen', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'flood')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (20841, N'Timothy', N'Mccoy', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'fear')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (21916, N'Troy', N'Chaney', CAST(N'1995-01-04' AS Date), N'rise')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (22548, N'Jodi', N'Chaney', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'provide')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (22717, N'Arsenio', N'Douglas', CAST(N'1995-02-04' AS Date), N'fair')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (23934, N'Carla', N'Warner', CAST(N'1995-03-04' AS Date), N'threat')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (24149, N'Troy', N'Mccoy', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'reserve')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (24698, N'Jennifer', N'Mcclain', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'commo')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (25517, N'Kato', N'Vance', CAST(N'1995-08-04' AS Date), N'build')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (25543, N'Hiram', N'Clarke', CAST(N'1995-04-04' AS Date), N'gaffe')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (25980, N'Lionel', N'Mercado', CAST(N'1995-07-04' AS Date), N'war')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (26289, N'Kyle', N'Anderson', CAST(N'1995-11-04' AS Date), N'revenge')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (26376, N'Samuel', N'Carrillo', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'ignite')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (26471, N'Chad', N'Gates', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'theater')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (26611, N'Erica', N'Smith', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'lounge')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (27612, N'Yolanda', N'Hopkins', CAST(N'1995-02-04' AS Date), N'clothes')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (27648, N'John', N'Duncan', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'vertical')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (27666, N'Mitch', N'LaPine', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'straighte')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (27869, N'Otto', N'Nunez', CAST(N'1995-08-04' AS Date), N'visible')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (28307, N'Richard', N'Wolf', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'gold')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (28366, N'Kassie', N'Gibbs', CAST(N'1995-05-04' AS Date), N'colleague')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (28367, N'Kane', N'Douglas', CAST(N'1995-04-04' AS Date), N'rider')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (28592, N'Aquila', N'Morrison', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'reliable')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (28775, N'Gil', N'Chaney', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'wi')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (28996, N'Hiram', N'Vega', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'help')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (29308, N'Jackie', N'Merrill', CAST(N'1995-05-04' AS Date), N'dedicate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (29469, N'Troy', N'Pate', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'wide')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (29543, N'Stephanie', N'Rice', CAST(N'1995-08-04' AS Date), N'discipline')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (29735, N'Chancellor', N'Hopkins', CAST(N'1995-09-04' AS Date), N'arena')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (29819, N'Erica', N'Knox', CAST(N'1995-12-04' AS Date), N'bald')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (30624, N'Devin', N'Hughey', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'approval')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (31053, N'Jackie', N'Merrill', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'champio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (31065, N'Ida', N'Wolf', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'crew')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (31424, N'Yolanda', N'Wright', CAST(N'1995-07-04' AS Date), N'cut')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (31913, N'Stephanie', N'Delgado', CAST(N'1995-09-04' AS Date), N'laundry')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (32492, N'Hope', N'Good', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'tired')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (32791, N'Raja', N'Carrillo', CAST(N'1995-05-04' AS Date), N'husband')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (32944, N'Maggie', N'Vega', CAST(N'1995-10-04' AS Date), N'porter')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (32997, N'Colt', N'Clarke', CAST(N'1995-01-04' AS Date), N'monstrous')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (34388, N'Devin', N'Lundeen', CAST(N'1995-07-04' AS Date), N'appreciate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (34753, N'Josiah', N'Gunter', CAST(N'1995-11-04' AS Date), N'hostility')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (34835, N'Timothy', N'Chaney', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'proposal')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (34908, N'Erica', N'Dingman', CAST(N'1995-05-04' AS Date), N'terms')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (35075, N'Gil', N'Pate', CAST(N'1995-09-04' AS Date), N'appendix')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (35387, N'Kennedy', N'Smith', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'nightmare')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (302, N'Dolan', N'LaPine', CAST(N'1995-07-03' AS Date), N'ghost')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (672, N'Devin', N'Jensen', CAST(N'1995-09-03' AS Date), N'rock')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (686, N'Ciaran', N'Wright', CAST(N'1995-03-03' AS Date), N'canvas')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (1038, N'Lamar', N'Jensen', CAST(N'1995-05-03' AS Date), N'worth')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (1118, N'Richard', N'Stuart', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'wago')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (2414, N'Victor', N'Vega', CAST(N'1995-02-03' AS Date), N'problem')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (2507, N'John', N'Mcclain', CAST(N'1995-09-03' AS Date), N'greeting')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (2665, N'Barb', N'Sanchez', CAST(N'1995-01-03' AS Date), N'presidential')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (2973, N'Lewis', N'Gibbs', CAST(N'1995-05-03' AS Date), N'weed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3155, N'Chancellor', N'Duncan', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'smash')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3382, N'Colt', N'Duncan', CAST(N'1995-11-03' AS Date), N'thaw')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (3589, N'Donna', N'Newton', CAST(N'1995-03-03' AS Date), N'introductio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (4369, N'Tonya', N'Douglas', CAST(N'1995-02-03' AS Date), N'timber')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (4548, N'Kane', N'Coleman', CAST(N'1995-06-03' AS Date), N'voucher')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (4740, N'Devin', N'Gates', CAST(N'1995-07-03' AS Date), N'retirement')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (4920, N'Lionel', N'Krause', CAST(N'1995-08-03' AS Date), N'eyebrow')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (5344, N'Lisa', N'Rice', CAST(N'1995-11-03' AS Date), N'source')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (6303, N'Jennifer', N'Mcclain', CAST(N'1995-02-03' AS Date), N'day')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (6763, N'George', N'Dow', CAST(N'1995-10-03' AS Date), N'achieve')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (7169, N'Honorato', N'Morrison', CAST(N'1995-09-03' AS Date), N'extort')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (7199, N'Josiah', N'Vega', CAST(N'1995-03-03' AS Date), N'indicatio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (7766, N'Quinn', N'Delgado', CAST(N'1995-11-03' AS Date), N'romantic')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (8839, N'Otto', N'Espinoza', CAST(N'1995-01-03' AS Date), N'chair')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (8855, N'Victor', N'Mccoy', CAST(N'1995-08-03' AS Date), N'trustee')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (9152, N'Hiram', N'Hopkins', CAST(N'1995-09-03' AS Date), N'flock')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (9551, N'John', N'Merrill', CAST(N'1995-07-03' AS Date), N'mother')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (9638, N'Nancy', N'Hopkins', CAST(N'1995-07-03' AS Date), N'creatio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (11165, N'Josiah', N'Rowland', CAST(N'1995-07-04' AS Date), N'exercise')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (11430, N'Todd', N'Mcclain', CAST(N'1995-03-04' AS Date), N'collectio')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (13100, N'Donovan', N'Vance', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'post')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID], [FIrstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth], [VerificationCode]) VALUES (13497, N'George', N'Krause', CAST(N'1995-06-04' AS Date), N'captai')
```

GO

Comment: >43Mb of "sample" data? That's very generous but I'm afraid I do not have the time to deal with that much. The concept of "sample" is to be small. In fact you might want to consider ["Minimal Complete Verifiable Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I'll reduce it.

Comment: Question should be much better described now @Used_By_Already , apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Revised answer provided. (& Thanks for the SQLfiddle.)

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already, that seems to match, but could you see why on the SQLFiddle the 3rd query shows Richard 1995 when that record and others don't match any of the criteria? If that should be another question let me know as I know it wasn't mentioned originally. Testing your statement, if I change the "or" to an "and", it gets the correct result, so it's back to the original problem with my results.

Comment: query 3 result: search word is '1995' and the name is 'Richard 1995' which contains the search term. *So I'm not following why you don't expect it.* Are you clear in you own mind about what it is you need?  And: If you change an OR to AND you go back to the same problem .... no sure why you would do that isn't the point of the question to avoid the problem?

Comment: For the 3rd query the parameters are    DECLARE SearchWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'geo',     DECLARE LowerDate DATE = '01 Jan 1995' ,     DECLARE UpperDate DATE = '31 Dec 1995'. The first result, ClientID 206 doesn't match any of those parameter but appears, and it seems to be with your suggested OR statement addition to solve the AND/OR problem.

Comment: Define "3rd query" is its the 3rd query in my answer or something new? if new I need the URL.

Comment: It should be in the Fiddle, in the original post - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68162/15

Comment: because the SearchWords table contains the "word" 1995

Comment: LOL, cheers dude, all good.

Comment: Yippee, got here. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches both expected results:

```
or (
     (@LowerDate IS NOT NULL AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN @LowerDate AND @UpperDate)
    )
```

**Query 1**:

```
    DECLARE @SearchWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'li'
    DECLARE @LowerDate DATE = NULL
    DECLARE @UpperDate DATE = NULL

SELECT
    'Suggest1',
    ClientID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    VerificationCode,
    DateOfBirth
FROM Clients c
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM SearchWordsTwo s
          WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
        )
or (
     (@LowerDate IS NOT NULL AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN @LowerDate AND @UpperDate)
    )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63fe1/2/0)**:

```
|          | ClientID | FirstName | LastName | VerificationCode | DateOfBirth |
|----------|----------|-----------|----------|------------------|-------------|
| Suggest1 |     1506 |    George |  Coleman |       brilliance |  1995-06-03 |
| Suggest1 |     2600 |      Lisa |  Stanley |             rice |  1995-06-03 |
| Suggest1 |     2984 |    Lionel |     Knox |       disappoint |  1995-05-03 |
| Suggest1 |     3206 |    Lionel |  Stanley |          reflect |  1995-02-03 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- -------------------------------------------
     --works correctly with an AND for DateOfBirth
    DECLARE @SearchWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'li'
    DECLARE @LowerDate DATE = NULL
    DECLARE @UpperDate DATE = NULL

SELECT
    'Correct1',
    ClientID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    VerificationCode,
    DateOfBirth
FROM Clients c
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM SearchWordsTwo s
          WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
        )
  AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DateOfBirth)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63fe1/2/1)**:

```
|          | ClientID | FirstName | LastName | VerificationCode | DateOfBirth |
|----------|----------|-----------|----------|------------------|-------------|
| Correct1 |     1506 |    George |  Coleman |       brilliance |  1995-06-03 |
| Correct1 |     2600 |      Lisa |  Stanley |             rice |  1995-06-03 |
| Correct1 |     2984 |    Lionel |     Knox |       disappoint |  1995-05-03 |
| Correct1 |     3206 |    Lionel |  Stanley |          reflect |  1995-02-03 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- -------------------------------------------

    DECLARE @SearchWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1995'
    DECLARE @LowerDate DATE = '01 Jan 1995'
    DECLARE @UpperDate DATE = '31 Dec 1995'

SELECT
    'Suggest2',
    ClientID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    VerificationCode,
    DateOfBirth
FROM Clients c
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM SearchWords s
          WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
        )
or (
     (@LowerDate IS NOT NULL AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN @LowerDate AND @UpperDate)
    )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63fe1/2/2)**:

```
|          | ClientID |    FirstName |   LastName | VerificationCode | DateOfBirth |
|----------|----------|--------------|------------|------------------|-------------|
| Suggest2 |      206 | Richard 1995 |    Douglas |              bee |  1948-01-03 |
| Suggest2 |      404 |        thank | yourselves |           whattt |  1995-12-03 |
| Suggest2 |      670 |     Ida 1995 |    Delgado |             mild |  1995-02-03 |
| Suggest2 |     1506 |       George |    Coleman |       brilliance |  1995-06-03 |
| Suggest2 |     2384 |        Lewis |       Rice |       instrument |  1995-04-03 |
| Suggest2 |     2600 |         Lisa |    Stanley |             rice |  1995-06-03 |
| Suggest2 |     2974 |      Hammett |    Hopkins |          snuggle |  1995-05-03 |
| Suggest2 |     2984 |       Lionel |       Knox |       disappoint |  1995-05-03 |
| Suggest2 |     3105 |       Ciaran |    Delgado |            strip |  1995-11-03 |
| Suggest2 |     3206 |       Lionel |    Stanley |          reflect |  1995-02-03 |
| Suggest2 |     3317 |        Ethan |       Rice |              bay |  1995-06-03 |
| Suggest2 |     3534 |         Jack |      Vance |         security |  1995-04-03 |
| Suggest2 |     3654 |         Elmo |      Smith |              sum |  1995-01-03 |
| Suggest2 |     3881 |     Michelle |      Watts |            night |  1995-11-03 |
| Suggest2 |     4533 |         Otto |    Hopkins |           appeal |  1995-06-03 |
| Suggest2 |     4929 |       Carlos |   Harrison |             gree |  1995-02-03 |
| Suggest2 |     5052 |        Hiram |      Nunez |            rumor |  1995-08-03 |
| Suggest2 |     5148 |    Stephanie |    Russell |           expect |  1995-05-03 |
| Suggest2 |     5240 |         Kato |      Gibbs |       appearance |  1995-06-03 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
-- -------------------------------------------

   --works correctly with an OR for DateOfBirth
    DECLARE @SearchWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1995'
    DECLARE @LowerDate DATE = '01 Jan 1995'
    DECLARE @UpperDate DATE = '31 Dec 1995'

SELECT
    'Correct2',
    ClientID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    VerificationCode,
    DateOfBirth
FROM Clients c
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM SearchWords s
          WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
        )
  OR DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DateOfBirth)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63fe1/2/3)**:

```
|          | ClientID |    FirstName |   LastName | VerificationCode | DateOfBirth |
|----------|----------|--------------|------------|------------------|-------------|
| Correct2 |      206 | Richard 1995 |    Douglas |              bee |  1948-01-03 |
| Correct2 |      404 |        thank | yourselves |           whattt |  1995-12-03 |
| Correct2 |      670 |     Ida 1995 |    Delgado |             mild |  1995-02-03 |
| Correct2 |     1506 |       George |    Coleman |       brilliance |  1995-06-03 |
| Correct2 |     2384 |        Lewis |       Rice |       instrument |  1995-04-03 |
| Correct2 |     2600 |         Lisa |    Stanley |             rice |  1995-06-03 |
| Correct2 |     2974 |      Hammett |    Hopkins |          snuggle |  1995-05-03 |
| Correct2 |     2984 |       Lionel |       Knox |       disappoint |  1995-05-03 |
| Correct2 |     3105 |       Ciaran |    Delgado |            strip |  1995-11-03 |
| Correct2 |     3206 |       Lionel |    Stanley |          reflect |  1995-02-03 |
| Correct2 |     3317 |        Ethan |       Rice |              bay |  1995-06-03 |
| Correct2 |     3534 |         Jack |      Vance |         security |  1995-04-03 |
| Correct2 |     3654 |         Elmo |      Smith |              sum |  1995-01-03 |
| Correct2 |     3881 |     Michelle |      Watts |            night |  1995-11-03 |
| Correct2 |     4533 |         Otto |    Hopkins |           appeal |  1995-06-03 |
| Correct2 |     4929 |       Carlos |   Harrison |             gree |  1995-02-03 |
| Correct2 |     5052 |        Hiram |      Nunez |            rumor |  1995-08-03 |
| Correct2 |     5148 |    Stephanie |    Russell |           expect |  1995-05-03 |
| Correct2 |     5240 |         Kato |      Gibbs |       appearance |  1995-06-03 |
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work for the first set of parameters.

Comment: how does it "not work"? does smoke emit from the screen? you provide no test case so how do I know what you are talking about?

Comment: have you considered that a nvarchar value of N'1995' may be the "not work" source? (i.e. if you ignore birthdate altogether do you get results from the search word N'1995'). sample data would sure help here

Comment: Hahaha thanks for a good laugh.  Smoke didn't quite emit from the screen, but it was close ;)  I think I issue is within your first statement you have "AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN @LowerDate AND @UpperDate" as it isn't bringing back results at all except on the Word component of the query.

Comment: without test data we could spend the next 24 hrs exchanging messages and getting nowhere, only you have that test data (so far, hint)

Comment: Sample data link posted.

Comment: Thanks - if you change your @SearchWords to 1950 for example, there are no results. It should show Fred, Barney and Wilma because they were born in 1950.

Comment: AH!, this small but vital piece is missing from your question... so you expect dates to be treated as text as well as being dates... v.weird

Comment: It doesn't need to consider the Word (1950) on DOB, only within the Text fields as per my original query. With your example, change "xyz" to "1950". This returns 0 rows, but should return 2.

Comment: I'm giving up now, perhaps someone else can ascertain what it is you are asking for. You might consider setting-up a sqlfidde like I did bit this time also add "the expected result" for EACH SET of parameters. have fun. ps: avoid terms like "it doesn't work"

Comment: Thanks anyway, problem with SQL fiddle is that it's only SQL 2014 and theres a bunch of later functions used.